# complex numbers plane

Tags: complex-numbers

If we know that $A = 1+6i$ and $B = 10−7i$ are two points of the square $ABCD$, then what are the possible values of $C$ and $D$.

As it's square thought to my self that the sides are equal so I tried to solve it with calculating the length of the vector between these two points but I ended up with $\sqrt{-112}$ and I also realized even if I would find a pure number how should I apply it to the points that I have with an angle $90$.

Comment: In complex numbers, multiplication by $i$ is rotation over $90^{\circ}$.

Comment: Just imagine the real part as the $x$ coordinate and the imaginary part as the $y$ coordinate. So $A$ would be the point $(1|6)$ and B the point $10|-7$. I am sure you can compute the distance between those points.
Then use @Wouter's comment to compute the other points.